# Adding an object to a list Python OOP

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to python OOP. I'm trying to create a method that gets user's input (book name, author and genre), creates a book Object and adds it to a list only if such a book doesn't exist. Initially, I wanted to use `__eq__` but couldn't find a way to make it work...

Here my code:

```
class Book:
def __init__(self, book_name, author_name, genre):
    self.book_name = book_name
    self.author_name = author_name
    self.genre = genre
    self.booksList=[]

def __eq__(self, other):
    if (self.book_name == other.book_name):
        return True
    else: 
        return False
    
def __str__(self):
    return f"The book {self.book_name} written by {self.author_name} is {self.genre}"

def addBook(self, book_name, author_name, genre):
    if book_name not in self.booksList:
      self.booksList.append(book_name)
      print("success")
    else:
        print("Book already exists")
```

````
while True:
    option=input("choose an operation:\n \n") 
    
    if option not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']:
            print("Please enter a valid operation")

    if (option=="1"):
                  book_name=input ('Enter book name:')
                  author_name = input ('Enter author name:')
                  genre= input ('Enter genre:')
                  new_book=Book(book_name, author_name, genre)
                  new_book.addBook(book_name, author_name, genre)
              
            #option2  
    elif (option=="2"):
                  pass```
````

Comment: Explain what doesn't work, what happens, what should happen?

Comment: I would like to add the new book only if such a book doesn't exist in the list (display the error message and don't append it). However, it seems to append a book even if I add the same exact book over and over.

Comment: better to strip for spaces on bookname and then do the condition check, ie. `if book_name.strip() not in self.booklist:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to add a book to the list of the instance itself.
A simple solution with dunder methods would be the following:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, book_name, author_name, genre):
        self.book_name = book_name
        self.author_name = author_name
        self.genre = genre
        

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self.book_name == other.book_name):
            return True
        else: 
            return False
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"The book {self.book_name} written by {self.author_name} is {self.genre}"

books = []
while True:
    option=input("[-] Choose an operation:\n") 
    
    if option not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']:
            print("Please enter a valid operation")

    if option == "1":

                book_name=input ('Enter book name:')
                author_name = input ('Enter author name:')
                genre= input ('Enter genre:')
                new_book=Book(book_name, author_name, genre)
                
                if len(books) > 0:
                    for i, book in enumerate(books):
                        if new_book == book:
                            break
                        else:
                            if i == len(books)-1:
                                books.append(new_book)
                else:
                    books.append(new_book)



            
    elif option == "2":
        for e in books:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Just to mention that `__eq__` body can be just `return self.book_name == other.book_name`. And to allow for books with same name, but different author, can compare tuple of `(name, author)`.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you could do something like this:

```
class Book:
    booksList={}
    def __init__(self, book_name, author_name, genre):
        self.book_name = book_name
        self.author_name = author_name
        self.genre = genre
        self.booksList[book_name] = {
            "name":book_name,
            "author":author_name,
            "genre":genre
        }

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self.book_name == other.book_name):
            return True
        else: 
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return f"The book {self.book_name} written by {self.author_name} is {self.genre}"

    def addBook(self, book_name, author_name, genre):
        if book_name not in self.booksList:
          self.booksList[book_name] = {
            "name":book_name,
            "author":author_name,
            "genre":genre
        }
          print("success")
        else:
            print("Book already exists")
```